# Cookie Policy Pop Up not saving response

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, cookies, gdprconsentform

Deploying my first Dotnet 6 c# web application. Just deployed, and added a cookie policy pop up for GDPR, following instructions on Microsoft site [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/gdpr?view=aspnetcore-6.0)

The cookie pop up works as expected locally, but when I deploy to temp url on smarterasp, the cookie pop up appears on every page no matter if you click ok on it or not.

My code is as follows:
Program.cs

```
builder.Services.Configure<CookiePolicyOptions>(options =>
{
    options.CheckConsentNeeded = context => true;
    options.MinimumSameSitePolicy = SameSiteMode.None;
});
```

```
app.UseCookiePolicy();
```

In script section of layout (also previously had it in a custom.js file):

```
<script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $("#cookieConsentdiv button[data-cookie-string]").bind("click", function () {
                document.cookie = $("#cookieConsentdiv button").attr("data-cookie-string");
                $("#cookieConsentdiv").hide();
            });
           
        });
    </script>
```

And cookie consent partial view which is loaded in main section of page:

```
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Features

@{
    var consentFeature = Context.Features.Get<ITrackingConsentFeature>();
    var showBanner = !consentFeature?.CanTrack ?? false;
    var cookieString = consentFeature?.CreateConsentCookie();
}

@if (showBanner)
{
    <div id="cookieConsentdiv">
        <h3 class="display-6">Cookie Policy</h3>
        <p>We value your privacy. We use cookies only to enhance your browsing experience. <a asp-action="Privacy" asp-controller="Home">Learn More</a>.</p>
        <button type="button" data-cookie-string="@cookieString">
            <span aria-hidden="true">Accept</span>
        </button>
    </div>
}
```